# React Javascript, creating new arrays from existing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array and I need to create new array based on existing.

```
function CartDetails() {


  const items = [ {"id": 14,'name' :'d'},{ "id": 15,'name' :'c'}]  // FROM THIS ARRAY I NEED TO COPY

 let newarray= [] // RESULTANT ARRAY

useEffect(()=>{

    for (let i in items){ quantity.push(i.id:1)} // MY METHOD OF ARRAY COPY but it is wrong
        },[])

    return (</>)


export default CartDetails
```

I want to copy the `id` from parent array and add to new array,

expected result `newarray = [{ 14:1},{ 15:1}]`, here 14 and 15 are parent array ID's and 1 is constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```js
const items = [ {"id": 14,'name' :'d'},{ "id": 15,'name' :'c'}]
const newArray = items.map(item => ({[item.id]:1}));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, How do {item.id} method gets wrong ? and [item.id] is the correct way

Comment: Since you want to create an object item, you have to use the curly braces. Then assign the ID as the key - i.e. to the left of the colon and the value to its right.
I used square brackets on the left hand side as the key is dynamic - meaning each iteration will provide a different key and it's not hard coded. (`{age: 20}` vs `{[currentProperty]: some value}`)

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArr = items.map(item => {
      return {
       [item.id] : 1
      }
    })
```

check this out

Comment: var newItems = [...items].map(i => ({[i.id]: 1}))

Comment: why you need  [...items] . basicly, map not modify your own array (items)